# sql query how to put 2 "where"condition

Tags: sql, vb.net

[image]

first this is the table relationship.
below is what i'm trying to achieve

```
Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT inventory.ItemName,record_item.Amount FROM record_item,inventory WHERE (record_item.RecordID = '" & listbox1.SelectedItem & "')", conn)
```

if i'm trying to get ItemName based on the RecordID that i have,do i need to put 2 condition? if i do, how?

`WHERE (record_item.RecordID = '" & listbox1.SelectedItem & "')` and `WHERE(record_item.ItemID=inventory.ItemID)`

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE (something) AND (something else)
```

Answer (score 2):

just do:

```
SELECT inventory.ItemName,record_item.Amount FROM record_item,inventory
WHERE record_item.RecordID = '" & listbox1.SelectedItem & "' and record_item.ItemID=inventory.ItemID
```

Comment: If it worked for you then could you mark the answer as Accepted.. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Without** second `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE 
    (record_item.RecordID = '" & listbox1.SelectedItem & "') 
and (record_item.ItemID=inventory.ItemID)
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of using two where condition you can use like this

WHERE (1st condition) AND (2nd condition).

Answer (score 0):

> Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT inventory.ItemName,record_item.Amount 
>   FROM record_item,inventory WHERE record_item.RecordID = '" & listbox1.SelectedItem & "' AND record_item.ItemID=inventory.ItemID", conn)

Answer (score 0):

Check below code...

`Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT inventory.ItemName, record_item.Amount FROM  record_item, inventory WHERE (record_item.RecordID = '" & listbox1.SelectedItem & "' AND record_item.ItemID=inventory.ItemID)", conn)`

If your `record_item.RecordID` is Integer, then below query would work...

`Dim ad As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT inventory.ItemName, record_item.Amount FROM  record_item, inventory WHERE (record_item.RecordID = " & listbox1.SelectedItem & " AND record_item.ItemID=inventory.ItemID)", conn)`

Answer (score 0):

Can't use more than one WHERE in simple SELECT query, either you can use SUBQUERY or other.

in your case, why you are not implement suggested answer.
also you can use IN clause like,

```
WHERE (record_item.RecordID IN ('" & listbox1.SelectedItem & "', inventory.ItemID )
```